# DefinitelyTyped TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015, definitelytyped

im trying to code in typescript using Angular library, and everytime i try to compile just give me 482 errors, where most of them are "TS 2304 Cannot find a name 'Promise'". I can´t fix this. Just a note, if i unistall angular library, it compiles with no error.

I install Angular 1.5, and Angular.d.ts requires Angular 1.4+, so no problem here.
I try to reinstall multiple times, still no changes.

For angular.d.ts i used a nuget package named angularjs.typescript.definitelytyped. Im using visual studio 2015 Update 1, with all the updates available today.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are not really giving us a lot to go on. You did not provide any code and it is your code that you are having problems with. It would be like trying to have a mechanic fix your car without you bringing in your car to their shop. See this post [how do i ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i dont really have a lot of code, but here it is. interface Iasd { asd: string; } class asd implements Iasd{ asd: string; }

If i dont install Angular Library, this dont blow up. Im sorry if you dont like my question, i will try to make a better one next time ;) But, theres nothing else i can show except this code that i paste, because thats the only code that i did...

Comment: In which file file and on which line do you get the error?

Comment: File: angular-component-router.d.ts, line 48, 90, etc, all the lines that have Promise in it.

Comment: Are you using a `Promise` polyfill for your app? If so, you'll need to include the typing definitions for it (core-js has [typings on DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/44c9273e1e92bc95368f599d1dcda9f560a68956/core-js/core-js.d.ts) for this). Otherwise, you'll need to use `--target es2015`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Daniel Rosenwasser's comment I added the core-js d.ts with
PM> Install-Package core-js.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped

That solved the problem for me.